# Proof of a double integral representation of Catalan's constant

Tags: calculus

Catalan's constant C (sometimes G) is defined by

$$C=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\approx0.915965594...$$

C has a variety of integral representation - I'm especially interested in this one:

$$C=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2}dxdy$$

How would you prove this identity?

Answer (score 2):

Take the double integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2}dxdy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+(xy)^2}dxdy$$

$$u=xy, \frac{du}{dx}=y, \frac{du}{y}=dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0*y}^{1*y}\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{1+u^2}dudy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{1+u^2}dudy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{y}[arctan(y)-arctan(0)]dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{arctan(y)}{y}dy$$

Taylor series expansion of inverse tangent:

$$arctan(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^ny(y^2)^n}{2n+1}$$

$$\frac{arctan(y)}{y}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(y^2)^n}{2n+1}$$

Our integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(y^2)^n}{2n+1}dy$$

Integrals and sums satisfy the multiplication by a constant rule and sum rule, so they can be rearranged like so:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{1}(y^2)^ndy$$

The use the power rule to integrate $(y^2)^n$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}[\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{0}{2n+1}]$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

Which by definition equals $C$.

Comment: What is the application of Catalan's constant please?